# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception on array map

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, array-map

I have a code that iterates on ArrayMap keys, and I got an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception from unknown reason

**From Crashalytics:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=56; index=56
android.util.ArrayMap$1.colGetEntry (ArrayMap.java:763)
android.util.MapCollections$ArrayIterator.next (MapCollections.java:55)
```

**The code looks like that:**

```
private ArrayMap<String,RequestData> handlers = new ArrayMap<>();

public void removeAllHandlers() {
    synchronized (handlers) {
        for (String s : handlers.keySet()) {
            handlers.remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```

the Exception happened at this line: `for (String s : handlers.keySet())`

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Comment: indices are 0 based in Java, the maximal index is 55, you are trying to retrieve the 57th element of an array with 56 elements. removing elements from a Map while iterating over the same map is asking for trouble.

Comment: How about `handlers.clear()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove from a `Map` or a `List` while iterating. 
Use the internal clear method of the `Map`/`List`.
For instance, `handlers.clear();`

Code:

```
private ArrayMap<String,RequestData> handlers = new ArrayMap<>();

public void removeAllHandlers() {
        synchronized (handlers) {
                handlers.clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private ArrayMap<String,RequestData> handlers = new ArrayMap<>();

public void removeAllHandlers() {
    synchronized (handlers) {
        ArrayMap<String,RequestData> tempHandlers = handlers;
        for (String s : tempHandlers.keySet()) {
            handlers.remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the ArrayMap that your are iterating over. This is an anti-pattern in Java and will cause error. I recommend you using another ArrayMap for your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Just as others mentioned, you cannot `remove(Object o)` in a `for loop`, you have to do that removal using [`Iterator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator) as

```
public void removeAllHandlers() {
    synchronized (handlers) {
            Iterator<String> keyIterator = handlers.keySet().iterator();
            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                 RequestData requestData = handlers.get(keyIterator.next());
                 if(iDontWant(requestData)) {
                     keyIterator.remove();
                 }
            }
    }
}
```